# Como popular um objeto com o retorno de uma consulta WebApi?

Tags: c#, xml, asp.net-web-api

Como popular a variável `_clientes` tipo `Cliente` com o retorno de uma consulta a uma `WebApi`?

Seguindo a ótima sugestão do [Damon Dudek](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/users/88312/damon-dudek) me deparei com o erro abaixo:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

```
    public class ClienteController : Controller
        {
            HttpClient _client;
            Uri _clienteUri;

            // GET: Cliente
            public ActionResult Index()
            {
                if (_client == null)
                {
                    _client = new HttpClient();
                    _client.BaseAddress = new Uri("http://localhost:58573");
                    _client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new System.Net.Http.Headers.MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));
                }
                ArrayOfCliente _clientes = Listar();
                return View(_clientes);
            }

        private ArrayOfCliente Listar()
        { 
            HttpResponseMessage response = _client.GetAsync("api/clientes").Result;
            ArrayOfCliente oPessoa = new ArrayOfCliente();

            if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
            {
                XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(ArrayOfCliente));

//
                using (TextReader reader = new StringReader(response))
                {
                    ArrayOfCliente result = (ArrayOfCliente)serializer.Deserialize(reader);
                }
            }
            else
            {
                Response.Write(response.StatusCode.ToString() + " - " + response.ReasonPhrase);
            }
            return oPessoa;
        }
```

**Retorno da WebApi:**

```
<ArrayOfCliente xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/Dominio.Apolo.Modelo">
<Cliente>
<ClienteId>3</ClienteId>
<DtCadastro>2017-08-22T00:00:00</DtCadastro>
<Nome>Artefatos</Nome>
<RazaoSocial>Art e Fatos</RazaoSocial>
<TipoPessoa>PJ</TipoPessoa>
</Cliente>
<Cliente>
<ClienteId>4</ClienteId>
<DtCadastro>2017-08-22T00:00:00</DtCadastro>
<Nome>Empresa e Ind.</Nome>
<RazaoSocial>Nicks Oliveira</RazaoSocial>
<TipoPessoa>PJ</TipoPessoa>
</Cliente>
</ArrayOfCliente>
```

**Model Cliente:**

```
public class Cliente
    {
        public int ClienteId { get; set; }
        public string Nome { get; set; }
        public string RazaoSocial { get; set; }
        public string TipoPessoa { get; set; }
        public DateTime DtCadastro { get; set; }
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

Você pode usar o Serialization do C#, conforme passos abaixo:

import da classe:

```
using System.Xml.Serialization;
```

Definir os elementos do seu XML na classe:

```
[XmlRoot(ElementName = "ArrayOfCliente", Namespace = "http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/Dominio.Apolo.Modelo")]
public class ArrayOfCliente
{
    [XmlElement("Cliente")]
    public List<cliente> cliente { get; set; }
}


public class cliente
{
    [XmlElement("ClienteId")]
    public int ClienteId { get; set; }

    [XmlElement("Nome")]
    public string Nome { get; set; }

    [XmlElement("RazaoSocial")]
    public string RazaoSocial { get; set; }

    [XmlElement("TipoPessoa")]
    public string TipoPessoa { get; set; }

    [XmlElement("DtCadastro")]
    public DateTime DtCadastro { get; set; }
}
```

Após isso, só chamar o XmlSerializer do C#:

```
    XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(ArrayOfCliente));
            using (TextReader reader = new StringReader(@"<ArrayOfCliente xmlns:i='http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance' xmlns='http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/Dominio.Apolo.Modelo'>
  <Cliente>
    <ClienteId>3</ClienteId>
    <DtCadastro>2017-08-22T00:00:00</DtCadastro>
    <Nome>Artefatos</Nome>
    <RazaoSocial>Art e Fatos</RazaoSocial>
    <TipoPessoa>PJ</TipoPessoa>
  </Cliente>
  <Cliente>
    <ClienteId>4</ClienteId>
    <DtCadastro>2017-08-22T00:00:00</DtCadastro>
    <Nome>Empresa e Ind.</Nome>
    <RazaoSocial>Nicks Oliveira</RazaoSocial>
    <TipoPessoa>PJ</TipoPessoa>
  </Cliente>
</ArrayOfCliente>"))
            {
                ArrayOfCliente result = (ArrayOfCliente)serializer.Deserialize(reader);
            }
```

Comment: Entendi, @Damon Dudek eu coloquei o **xml** no post para um melhor entendimento e fiquei na dúvida de como fazer para obter esse **xml** de forma dinâmica, algo assim `_clientes = response // dados do xml` ?

Comment: basta substituir a string que coloquei no StringReader pelo seu response

Comment: Bom dia @Damon Dudek voltei a implementar a solução e ocorre erro de conversão de tipo eu editei o post e adicionei um print de erro.

Comment: O que está chegando no seu responde? Faz um debug no objeto

Answer (score 1):

Por padrão o .Net tanto em webapi quando MVC trás um pacote chamado Newtonsoft.Json, com ele é possível fazer o deserialize do json para um objeto e o código ficaria como abaixo, porém como sua api está retornando XML, primeiro vc teria que transformar o xml em json.

OBS: caso sua api possa retornar json, seu problema se resolve com o código abaixo:

```
private Cliente Listar()
{
    HttpResponseMessage response = _client.GetAsync("api/clientes").Result;
    Cliente _clientes = new Cliente();
    if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
    {
          _clientes = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Cliente>(response);                   
    }
    else
        Response.Write(response.StatusCode.ToString() + " - " + response.ReasonPhrase);

    return _clientes;
}
```